# How to get app icon from store with angular?

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, app-store

I'm developing an app with ionic, angular and Cordova. 
In this app are some links to other apps in the app store.

My question is: Is it possible to get the icons from apps in the store?

I want to show the icons in my app. Clicking on them redirects the user to the store.
I have the app's name and id. If it just works with the name, it would be best.

Comment: iTunes Search API.

Comment: @Roope: This works! Thank you! Just for a single app I don't get data...

Comment: Would you like to add an answer? So, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple offers the iTunes Search API for things like this. See more here: https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/